# Difference between in background and does not have user interface?

Tags: android, asynchronous, service

A **Service** is an application component that can perform **long-running operations**

**1)  in the background**

and

**2) does do not provide a user interface**

both sound **same** to me (background and does not have a user interface).

I can suppose background **means** on another **process** or **thread** but service by default runs on the **main thread** in the **same** process.

Answer (score 1):

There are three different kind of `Services` - namely `Foreground`, `Background` and `Bound`.

A foreground service has a UI e.g. a status on the lock screen while a background service does not need to have one. And yes, a Service usually runs on the main thread and that's why it's suggested to create a `Thread` inside the `Service`.

The [android developer docs on services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) are actually quite comprehensive on this topic.

Comment: I want to know that what they want to tell us about with the term that service run in the background?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAliBaig Background means that the user does not interact with it directly e.g. a music player runs in the background while the user does something else inside the app. It also means that the services still runs in the background when the app is minimized and so on..

Comment: So background means service does not have a direct user interface

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAliBaig Yes mostly, see the docs. A background service performs an operation that isn't directly noticed by the user. For example, if an app used a service to compact its storage, that would usually be a background service.

Comment: I feel saying run in the background and does not have a user interface sounds same to me.

Comment: What does it means when we say that some of my components are running in the background. It appears to have two meanings for me 1) hidden from the user's eyes  2) running on some other thread or process

Comment: Can mean both, yes. UI components (eg activity, fragment) can be on the foreground or background. That is, either visible or not. Code can be executed on the main thread or another thread.. "another thread" means that it is running in the background